# validation of multiple check boxes for returned array in query

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I'm trying to check proper number of check boxes for a question that are selected.

jQuery script is:

```
$.validator.addMethod("q3", function(value, elem, param) {
    if($(".q3:checkbox:checked").length > 3){
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}, "You must select at least 4!");
```

and on the actual input I have:

```
<input class='{roles: true}' type="checkbox" name="q3[]" value="a"/>
```

Am I in left field with this or missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

found an easier way...

rules

```
        'q3[]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
            },
```

messages

```
        'q3[]': {
            required: "You must check at least 4 boxes",
            minlength: "Select more boxes."
        },
```